Unable to get l3keys choices conditional to work (latex3)
A follow up to Using \tl_put_right with grouping from latex3 explsyntax, I cannot seem to get choices to work here.
Naturally with:
\itemJ[ws=b]{First item}[This is the solution]

In the MWE below we expect it to print 'box', but it fails and prints notworking.
I am sure this is an extremely simple error that I have made, but have spent hours trying to figure this out with no luck!
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_harry_itemj_tmpa_tl

\keys_define:nn { harry / itemj }
  {
    opt .tl_set:N = \l_harry_itemj_options_tl,
    opt .initial:n = {},
    %
    ws .choice:,
    ws / b .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { box } },
    ws / l .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { line } }, 
    ws .default:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { none } }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{s O{} m O{}}{%
    \group_begin:    
    \keys_set_known:nn { harry / itemj } { #2 }
    \tl_gput_right:Ne \g_harry_itemj_tl
    {
        \exp_not:N 
            \task 
                \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}
                \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_harry_itemj_options_tl
                    {}
                    {[\l_harry_itemj_options_tl]}
        \exp_not:n 
        
        { #3 \\ 
        
        \tl_if_eq:nnTF {\l_harry_itemj_ws_tl} { box }
        { box }
        {
          \tl_if_eq:nnTF {\l_harry_itemj_ws_tl} { line }
            { line }
            { not working }
        }

        \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #4 } }
    \group_end:
    }


\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
  }
  {
    \tl_gclear:N \g_harry_itemj_tl
  }
  {
    \harry_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \g_harry_itemj_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ[ws=b]{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}(2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ[opt={(X)}]{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}](2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}

Output:


Are you sure you want to indiscriminately use \keys_set_known:nn? The result will be that any incorrect key will be silently ignored, meaning that a user might possibly not realise that the key they entered was slightly misspelled. For instance sw=box will not throw an error and if the user doesn't thoroughly proofread he might not notice this error.

You are absolutely right; what’s the alternative to prevent this?

use \set_keys:nn instead.

Your issue is that you put the \tl_if_eq:nnTF inside your \exp_not:n block, as such the values of \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl are not inserted there but instead once your code is actually executed there is a \tl_if_eq:nnTF { \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl } { line } which is never true.
Because of your .choice: setup you already have the means to parse which of the values is the correct one, why do you store that information in a tl only to reevaluate that later on? Instead the following will set the correct value in your choices, and only insert the current value of \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl in your \tl_gput_right:Ne, well that one I changed as well to a \tl_put_right:Nn and put it outside the group by using \exp_args:NNNe (there is no good reason to use a global variable here, imho).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_harry_itemj_tl
\tl_new:N \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { not~ working }

\keys_define:nn { harry / itemj }
  {
    opt .tl_set:N = \l_harry_itemj_options_tl,
    opt .initial:n = {},
    %
    ws .choice:,
    ws / b .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { box } },
    ws / l .code:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { line } }, 
    ws .default:n = { \tl_set:Nn \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl { none } }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{s O{} m O{}}
  {
    \group_begin:    
      \keys_set_known:nn { harry / itemj } { #2 }
      \exp_args:NNNe
    \group_end:
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_harry_itemj_tl
      {
        \exp_not:N 
            \task 
                \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}
                \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_harry_itemj_options_tl
                    {}
                    {[\l_harry_itemj_options_tl]}
        \exp_not:n { #3 \\ }
        \exp_not:V \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl
        \exp_not:n { \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #4 }
      }
  }


\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
  }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_harry_itemj_tl
  }
  {
    \harry_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_harry_itemj_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ[ws=b]{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}(2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ[opt={(X)}]{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}](2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}


Great solution, thank you so much.
I should have stated that I wasn’t wanting box and line to be printed there ultimately as literals; instead I will place other code there (a box of height set in proportion to a dimension set as a key, lines of number set by a key etc.)
Is it best to turn \exp_not:V \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl into a conditional and then place this code here? Or better to define lines and boxes as their own functions and reference them within the keys definition instead of line and box literal at present in the keys definition.

You can just put the code into \l_harry_itemj_ws_tl instead of the words box, line, or none or not~ working.
